# Use Smartcard Reader on Azure Remote Desktop

Tags: azure, windows-server-2016, usb, smartcard

What I want to achieve:

1. Plug a Smartcard Reader on my Laptop
2. Connect to my private Azure VPN
3. Use Remote Desktop to access a Server using User and Password, with Intelligent Card option and USBs **checked**.
4. My Smartcard Reader appears on my device so I can sign a document in a specific application

What actually happens: Smartcard Reader never appears on my Remote Machine.

What I did try (no specific order):

- On Remote Desktop window, checking all devices options
- Adding a new Device through Devices and Printers' window
- Checking Windows' Device Manager
- Plugging the Card Reader before and after authentication

Is there something I'm missing here? Maybe some option on Azure Firewall, or something else I must install on my server?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the smartcard drivers on the remote computer, same driver as the local computer if they are not discovered on connection.

Make sure the `ScDeviceEnum` service (*Smart Card Device Enumeration Service*) is not disabled.

**Edit 1**: If your remote endpoint is an Azure VM, the option to have remote USB device supported is not supported yet.. See that feedback.

- [Dead original link](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216843-virtual-machines/suggestions/8040390-usb-devices-are-not-supported-in-azure-vms)
- [Archived version of link](https://web.archive.org/web/20201130085031/https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216843-virtual-machines/suggestions/8040390-usb-devices-are-not-supported-in-azure-vms): From Feedback.Azure.com: *USB devices are not supported in Azure VMs*

Comment: ScDeviceEnum was disabled, I did enable and made logoff then logon again, unfortunately the problem still persists. About the driver, this same smartcard reader is listed as "SmartCard Reader" on my Laptop using Windows 10 and I still can't add it on Remote Machine using Add Device or similar ways.

Comment: @Carbon Can you validate if the remote machine got a usb controller in device manager ? I had a redirection issue too that way, as the remote can't use the usb device, thus can’t map it

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't, there's an unknown device which's shown even when the Smartcard Reader is not plugged. I tried to install Smartcard Reader driver on it, but looks like it wasn't the correct. What did you do to correct this case you just mentioned? Thanks!

Comment: By the way, it's possible to include External USB Hard Drive on my Laptop and connect it to the Remote Machine.

Comment: @Carbon In my case I went into the machine and added the usb controller, but it was on hyper-v/esx, I'am looking around in my azure portal, and I don't see any option to change the hardware on azure, and some forum post seem to think it's not supported into azure (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8c7f9e53-9b77-4514-b570-86a556c534cf/using-usb-devices-in-azure-vms?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows) I guess if true, it's why we can't add the USB hardware

Comment: Same here, couldn't find anything to achieve this. If it's a limitation of this platform then unfortunately I'll have to find another way. Thanks for helping me all the day!